# Could not transfer artifact maven-compiler-plugin from central

Tags: maven, eclipse-indigo

I have just downloaded Eclipse Indigo and the m2e plugin, and this error shows up in the `pom.xml` of my project :

```
ArtifactResolutionException: 
  Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 
  from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
  resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:
  maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
  null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom
```

I find the original error message to be weird with the `null`.
I checked that last url and there is indeed a `pom` file there.

I have tried specifying a mirror in my `settings.xml` but it doesn't seem to look there anyway, apparently.

Also, when I type `mvn clean` I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message. How come ?

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Failure to get the POM for a dependency is not considered an error.  It is just a warning.  This explains why `mvn clean` is successful.  As far as your settings not being consulted have you ensured that you have configured M2E to use *your* settings file?

Comment: Actually, this warning is at the root of a `CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: ... maven-compiler-plugin ...`. As for the settings, I did specify it in the Maven preferences (in Eclipse). How can I make sure it does try the mirror ?

Comment: @krookedking Make sure it does try **what** mirror?  Maven is going to search only the repositories specified in the settings.  If you specify mirrors in the settings those will be searched as well.  As for **ensuring** you can always try specifying the `-e` switch.  That's easier to implement if you coerce M2Eclipse to use your _external_ Maven installation.